# installing gomobile on mac OS Sierra 10.12

Tags: go, gomobile

I am trying to install gomobile on mac OS Sierra 10.12. I have go version 1.7.1 installed.

After doing the steps given below :

1. `go get golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile`
2. `gomobile init`

I get the following errors

```
gomobile: go install -pkgdir=/usr/local/mobgo/pkg/gomobile/pkg_darwin_arm std failed: exit status 2
# internal/poll
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:194:6: missing function body
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_mutex.go:195:6: missing function body
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:17:6: missing function body
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:19:6: missing function body
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:20:6: missing function body
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:21:6: missing function body
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:22:6: missing function body
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:23:6: missing function body
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:24:6: missing function body
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:25:6: missing function body
../go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:25:6: too many errors
```

Comment: I fixed it by upgrading my go version to 1.9.2. It seems OS sierra requires at least go1.7.4 or above.

Comment: You can post this comment as an answer, to resolve the question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by upgrading my go version to 1.9.2. It seems OS sierra requires at least go1.7.4 or above. –